# Differential equation $x' = 2tx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Take $x$ as a function of $t$.
Solve $$x' = 2tx \qquad\text{with}\qquad x(0) = 4$$

To solve this I used the general solution: if $x' = kx$  then   $x = e^{kt}$.
Taking $k = 2t$ , I got the answer of $x(t) = 4 e^{2t^2}$.
The answer *should* be  $x(t) = 4e^{t^2}$.

Was I right to use the general solution in this case? I notice that for my answer to be correct I would need to take $k = t$. Am I right to assume so? What have I done wrong?

Comment: The problem is that in that general solution, k is a constant, whilst 2t is a variable, and so the solution is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x'=2tx\implies \frac{x'}x=2t\implies \int\frac{dx}x=\int 2t \,dt\implies \log(x)=t^2+C$$

Just continue.

Comment: I see thank you! This makes sense now that you've solved it in a different (and easier/familiar) way. I suppose since k isn't a constant, the general solution does not apply(?).

Comment: Look under "separation of variable in differential eqs".